Is there a way to write an AABA lead sheet without writing out the last A section?
Here's how I usually see the AABA form written out.  Please note that the second A section (from the beginning to the second volta) and the third one (marked C) are identical.  Is there a way to avoid this duplication?  More specifically, is there a commonly accepted way of doing this?  (The example here is from a reputable publisher who probably knew what they were doing so I expect the answer to be 'no' but I thought I'd ask anyway.)


This is normally achieved using Da Capo along with specific description about what to do then: that form is normally used with "al segno" or "al coda", but if the last A is actually identical to the second volta, you could just write it in text, eg.: "D.C. to 2." or "D.C. senza ritornello" (or "no rep."), which normally assumes the second volta as implicit. Note, though, that it's relatively common to explicitly rewrite the new "A" after the "B", even if it's identical.

It should be noted that repeat notation is only used when every part in an ensemble plays the same thing again. If any part has new notes here, that's a strong answer to why it's written out.

This lead sheets is pretty conventional regarding section repeats. Personally I would prefer the first system break at m. 4 not m.3 with 5 bars for the next system containing the two voltas. The "C" section really should be labeled "A".

@MichaelCurtis, do you think repeating rehearsal letters is a good idea?  I mean, as far as I know, in an orchestral score they serve the "start here" function (as in "play from letter X"), not the form analysis function.  I'm not sure about the lead sheet though.

@Ivan, I see what you mean, those are rehearsal letters not section labels.

After the B section, use D.S. (or D.C.) al Fine, with the “Fine” placed at the end of the A section’s second ending. By convention, repeats are not observed during the ritornello.
This is not often done in lead sheets, because it makes the form harder to follow. The eye has to travel to the top of the page three times each time through the form, which can lead to confusion.

It not only makes the form harder to follow but leaves the form ambiguous, since it doesn't make clear whether time first ending and repeat are to be played the second time -- in other words, whether the form is AA'BA or AA'BAA'.

Agree. While classical theory states that repeats are not played on DC, with jazz charts they usually are played. Best to avoid this ambiguity.

Often wants a Coda, too, so you can incorporate a grand finale. But it is used when minimising pages or page turns is desirable. If you can fit the whole piece on one or two pages, then it's presumably a big enough saving when printing a concert band or orchestral score.

@KrisVanBael At some point in time it was the norm in classical music to actually make the repetitions when playing Da Capo unless there was a note saying "senza repetione". Then at another point in time it became the norm to avoid the repetitions when playing Da Capo, thus if you want the repetitions the words "con repetione" is used.

Another option besides either a DS or DC to the 2nd end like Aaron said is DS or DC al coda. A third option is to place a repeat sign at the end of letter B and add a 3rd ending after B which only contains the final bar of A, or what is called C on this chart. This eliminates the ambiguity of whether or not to take the 1st ending on a DC or DS. Using a coda or a 3rd ending are very similar solutions. My preference if I were to do this would be DC al coda because otherwise the 2nd ending would be somewhat long, 9 bars.
Despite being able to do these things, it doesn’t make them a better option. As a long time player and sight reader I can tell you from experience that the less “road map” elements you put into a chart (DC, DS, Volta, coda, repeat signs, etc.) the better your chances are of having the chart played accurately. Since most music is generated by notation software there is hardly any effort involved in copy/pasting an A section at the end of a chart and you end up with a much cleaner and easier to read piece of music. In this case you are talking about only 32 bars. If I were making a chart for this tune I might not even bother with 1st and 2nd endings and have it read straight down.

Well said: "the less 'road map' ... the better."

@Aaron Over the decades that I have been playing many hours have been wasted deciphering road maps at rehearsals and many mistakes have been made at gigs by myself or other players because of them.

I'm adding a visual, because it may be hard for some to understand all the strange repeat terms.
Here is a shortened example using just two measures for each "section" of an AABA form.


D.C. (Da Capo): Repeat from the beginning.
D.C. al Coda : Repeat from the beginning up to To Coda, then continue at Coda.
A circle with a crosshair over it  is the coda sign
Measures in performance order (in Musescore) are: 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6

Any of those measures could be expanded to multiple measures as desired.
But, as everyone else has said, the typical way to do it is write out fully the final A section to avoid jumping over the B section all the way back to the beginning and then again all the way to the end.
